# How I implement combobox in a datagridview column?

Tags: .net, winforms, datagridview, combobox, ado.net

I want to build a datagridview with a Combobox Column in which user enter values to be searched in db/dataset/datatable. After the user enter 3 chars/numbers and above the searching Process begins. How can I do this?

```
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                    ComboBox comboBoxHeaderCell = new ComboBox();
                    int xPos = dataGridView2.Width;
                    xPos -= dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[1].Size.Width;
                    dataGridView2.Controls.Add(comboBoxHeaderCell);
                    comboBoxHeaderCell.Size = dataGridView2.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Size;
                    comboBoxHeaderCell.Location = new Point(xPos, 0);
                    comboBoxHeaderCell.Location = dataGridView2.GetCellDisplayRectangle(i, 0, true).Location;
                    xPos += comboBoxHeaderCell.Size.Width;
                    //comboBoxHeaderCell.DataSource=dtusers2;
                    //comboBoxHeaderCell.ValueMember = "Name1";
                    //comboBoxHeaderCell.DisplayMember = "Name2";
                    if (dr.HasRows)
                    {
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            comboBoxHeaderCell.Items.Add(dr[0].ToString());
                        }
                        c++;
                    }
               // }

            }
```

By this code only one combo box generated at (0,0) position. But I want it in all rows in column 1.

Comment: Why you need `combobox` instead of normal `textbox`?

Comment: @Fabio: Ok. If I use normal `textbox` in a `datagridview` then please give me the code with auto suggested value from database.

Comment: Sorry, this is your job :). Show what did you tried... even where you tried to find a answers..

Comment: Why don't you use a [DataGridViewComboBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)? I missed something?